# Automatically post Joomla article to mybb-board

Tags: joomla

We're currently running a Joomla 2.5.6 installation and just created a mybb-board for our site. However, we want to sync the new articles from the Joomla page with the board, so new articles automatically appear as a new thread in the forum.

Is there a plugin for that, or how can we achieve something like that?

We searched, but the only useful syncing-plugin seems to be JFusion, but it looks like it syncs users, only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use this approach, get an RSS feed up for your new articles.
2. Use the [RSS Feed Poster Mod](http://mods.mybb.com/view/rss-feed-poster) for mybb and give it this RSS